# How do I slice a periodic interval of data from a Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a meteorological data set with 15 min interval records from 4 years. I want to slice data from 30thMarch to 25th April of every year. How can I do it?

Thank you

Hugo

```
data = pd.read_csv(("/user_home/w_hugopires/dados/dados_meteo.csv"),names=['POM','DTM','RNF','WET','HMD','TMP','DEW','INF'])
data['DTM'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DTM'], coerce = True)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(data[['POM','DTM']].values.T)
data.index = idx

    POM DTM RNF WET HMD TMP DEW INF
QuintaVilar 2011-11-01 00:00:00  QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-11-01 00:15:00  QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:15:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-11-01 00:30:00  QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:30:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-11-01 00:45:00  QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:45:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-11-01 01:00:00  QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 01:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I guess I have also a duplicate index... But if I try to index only by DateTime, since it is not unique, it raises an error

Comment: provide some code or example here

Comment: It's done on the question. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like the example DataFrame you pasted is valid.

Comment: I guess my problem is more complicated. It is also related with the Time index

Comment: @TomAugspurger I have made some more research and I have reposted a more complete question. Could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
>>> import pandas as p
>>> dates = p.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=4000)
>>> df = p.DataFrame(index=dates,columns=['DTM','RNF','WET','HMD','TMP','DEW','INF'])
>>> rows = ['2000-01-04','2003-01-04','2008-09-28']
>>> df.head(2)
            DTM  RNF  WET  HMD  TMP  DEW  INF
2000-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2000-01-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[2 rows x 7 columns]
>>> df.tail(2)
            DTM  RNF  WET  HMD  TMP  DEW  INF
2010-12-12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010-12-13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[2 rows x 7 columns]

>>> df.ix[rows]
            DTM  RNF  WET  HMD  TMP  DEW  INF
2000-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2003-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2008-09-28  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I have made some more research and I have reposted a more complete question. Could you help me? Thanks